# Error Updating Freeform Pro

Tags: plugin-freeform, updating, freeform

I recently renewed many licenses on a previously-neglected site and have been attempting to update both the CMS and the plugins. Despite having a Freeform Pro license, the plugin appears as Freeform Lite on the update list, and attempting to update it from 2.3.0 to 2.5.27 results in the error message:

```
Error: Client error: POST https://api.craftcms.com/v1/composer-whitelist resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: {"message":"Unknown package/constraint: solspace/craft3-freeform@2.5.27"}
```

The CMS is currently at 3.0.41.1, and attempting to update to 3.4.22.1 results in an error also referencing Freeform:

```
Composer output: Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package solspace/craft3-freeform 2.5.27 exists as solspace/craft3-freeform[3.0.0-beta.1, 2.5.24, 2.5.23, 2.5.22, 2.5.21, 2.5.20, 2.5.19, 2.5.18, 2.5.17, 2.5.16, 2.5.15, 2.5.14, 2.5.13, 2.5.12, 2.5.11, 2.5.10, 2.5.9, 2.5.8, 2.5.7, 2.5.6, 2.5.5, 2.5.4, 2.5.3, 2.5.2, 2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.4.3, 2.4.2, 2.4.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.4, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0-beta.20, 2.0.0-beta.19, 2.0.0-beta.18, 2.0.0-beta.17, 2.0.0-beta.1, 2.0.0-beta.2, 2.0.0-beta.3, 2.0.0-beta.4, 2.0.0-beta.5, 2.0.0-beta.6, 2.0.0-beta.7, 2.0.0-beta.8, 2.0.0-beta.9, 2.0.0-beta.10, 2.0.0-beta.11, 2.0.0-beta.12, 2.0.0-beta.13, 2.0.0-beta.14, 2.0.0-beta.15, 2.0.0-beta.16] but these are rejected by your constraint.
Problem 2
- The requested package solspace/craft3-freeform (locked at 2.3.0, required as 2.5.27) is satisfiable by solspace/craft3-freeform[2.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.
```

Based on other posts here, I've attempted to remove the "3" from "craft3-freeform" in the composer.json file (since reverted) and have attempted to run "composer update", though it appears I do not have shell access here. I know these are some outdated versions here, but any recommendations?

Thanks for your time and insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, posting here in case someone runs into something similar. I opened up the composer.json file in the root and removed the line `"solspace/craft-freeform": "2.5.27"` from the "required" list.

From there, I was able to update Craft, and then I was able to update Freeform. All is well, and all up-to-date!